# How to set seed for random simulations with foreach and doMC packages?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest

I need to do some simulations and for debugging purposes I want to use `set.seed` to get the same result. Here is the example of what I am trying to do:

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)

set.seed(123)
a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
set.seed(123)
b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
```

Objects `a` and `b` should be identical, i.e. `sum(abs(a-b))` should be zero, but this is not the case. I am doing something wrong, or have I stumbled on to some feature?

I am able to reproduce this on two different systems with R 2.13 and R 2.14

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My default answer used to be "well then don't do that" (using [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach)) as the [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) package does this (reliably!) for you.

But as @Spacedman points out, Renaud's new [doRNG](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doRNG) is what you are looking for if you want to remain with the `doFoo` / [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach) family.

The real key though is a clusterApply-style call to get the seeds set on all nodes. And in a fashion that coordinated across streams.  Oh, and did I mention that [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) by Tierney, Rossini, Li and Sevcikova has been doing this for you for almost a decade?

*Edit:* And while you didn't ask about [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow), for completeness here is an example from the command-line:

```
edd@max:~$ r -lsnow -e'cl <- makeSOCKcluster(c("localhost","localhost"));\
         clusterSetupRNG(cl);\
         print(do.call("rbind", clusterApply(cl, 1:4, \
                                             function(x) { stats::rnorm(1) } )))'
Loading required package: utils
Loading required package: utils
Loading required package: rlecuyer
           [,1]
[1,] -1.1406340
[2,]  0.7049582
[3,] -0.4981589
[4,]  0.4821092
edd@max:~$ r -lsnow -e'cl <- makeSOCKcluster(c("localhost","localhost"));\
         clusterSetupRNG(cl);\
         print(do.call("rbind", clusterApply(cl, 1:4, \
                                             function(x) { stats::rnorm(1) } )))'
Loading required package: utils
Loading required package: utils
Loading required package: rlecuyer
           [,1]
[1,] -1.1406340
[2,]  0.7049582
[3,] -0.4981589
[4,]  0.4821092
edd@max:~$
```

*Edit:* And for completeness, here is your example combined with what is in the docs for [doRNG](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doRNG)

```
> library(foreach)
R> library(doMC)
Loading required package: multicore

Attaching package: ‘multicore’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    mclapply, mcparallel, pvec

R> registerDoMC(2)
R> library(doRNG)
R> set.seed(123)
R> a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
R> set.seed(123)
R> b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
R> identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE                     ## ie standard approach not reproducible
R>
R> seed <- doRNGseed()
R> a <- foreach(i=1:2,combine=cbind) %dorng% { rnorm(5) }
R> b <- foreach(i=1:2,combine=cbind) %dorng% { rnorm(5) }
R> doRNGseed(seed)
R> a1 <- foreach(i=1:2,combine=cbind) %dorng% { rnorm(5) }
R> b1 <- foreach(i=1:2,combine=cbind) %dorng% { rnorm(5) }
R> identical(a,a1) && identical(b,b1)
[1] TRUE                      ## all is well now with doRNGseed()
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for example with snow. I am not well versed in intricacies of parallel programming in R, so I started using `foreach` for its painless transition from non-parallel code to parallel. I knew that I was missing something.

Comment: Well, that's why we all started years ago with snow as the transition from the standard *apply() functions to parallel ones was easy :)

Answer (score 9):

Using `set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")` also does the trick and does not require an extra package:

```
set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}

set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}

identical(a,b)
# TRUE
```

Comment: This answer is far simpler than Dirk Eddulbuettel's answer.  Does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: I too was drawn to the simplicity of this solution, but I can't reproduce the result (using R 3.4.0 on Windows 7, `doParallel` 1.0.11, and `foreach` 1.4.3)

Comment: This obviously *doesn’t* work. The RNG needs to be re-seeded between calls. I’ve taken the liberty of fixing this answer (even though I changed its meaning) since [it’s been misleading people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64242123/1968).

Comment: Well, it obviously *used to work* in 2017! Thanks for updating the code.

Answer (score 5):

Is the doRNG package any use to you? I suspect your problem is due to two threads both splatting the random seed vector:

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really would have like to mark both as an answer, but Dirk's answer was more extensive. I've upvoted your answer nevertheless, since it contains enough information to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

For more complicated loops, you might have to include set.seed() *inside* of the for loop:

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
library(doRNG)

set.seed(123)
a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  create_something <- c(1, 2, 3)
  rnorm(5)
}
set.seed(123)
b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  create_something  <- c(4, 5, 6)
  rnorm(5)
}
identical(a, b)
# FALSE
```

versus

```
a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  create_something  <- c(1, 2, 3)
  set.seed(123)
  rnorm(5)
}
b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  create_something  <- c(4, 5, 6)
  set.seed(123)
  rnorm(5)
}
identical(a, b)
# TRUE
```

Comment: you can use `set.seed(i)` to have a different seed in each loop