# Fully reproducible parallel models using caret

Tags: r, r-caret, reproducible-research

When I run 2 random forests in caret, I get the exact same results if I set a random seed:

```
library(caret)
library(doParallel)

set.seed(42)
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', index=createFolds(iris$Species))

set.seed(42)
model1 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

set.seed(42)
model2 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

> all.equal(predict(model1, type='prob'), predict(model2, type='prob'))
[1] TRUE
```

However, if I register a parallel back-end to speed up the modeling, I get a different result each time I run the model:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

set.seed(42)
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', index=createFolds(iris$Species))

set.seed(42)
model1 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

set.seed(42)
model2 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

stopCluster(cl)

> all.equal(predict(model1, type='prob'), predict(model2, type='prob'))
[1] "Component 2: Mean relative difference: 0.01813729"
[2] "Component 3: Mean relative difference: 0.02271638"
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?  One suggestion was to use the [doRNG](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/index.html) package, but `train` uses nested loops, which currently aren't supported:

```
library(doRNG)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
registerDoRNG()

set.seed(42)
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', index=createFolds(iris$Species))

set.seed(42)
> model1 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)
Error in list(e1 = list(args = seq(along = resampleIndex)(), argnames = "iter",  : 
  nested/conditional foreach loops are not supported yet.
See the package's vignette for a work around.
```

UPDATE:
I thought this problem could be solved using `doSNOW` and `clusterSetupRNG`, but I couldn't quite get there.

```
set.seed(42)
library(caret)
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(8, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', index=createFolds(iris$Species))

clusterSetupRNG(cl, seed=rep(12345,6))
a <- clusterCall(cl, runif, 10000)
model1 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

clusterSetupRNG(cl, seed=rep(12345,6))
b <- clusterCall(cl, runif, 10000)
model2 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

all.equal(a, b)
[1] TRUE
all.equal(predict(model1, type='prob'), predict(model2, type='prob'))
[1] "Component 2: Mean relative difference: 0.01890339"
[2] "Component 3: Mean relative difference: 0.01656751"

stopCluster(cl)
```

What's special about foreach, and why doesn't it use the seeds I initiated on the cluster? objects `a` and `b` are identical, so why not `model1` and `model2`?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8358098/324364) question will provide some useful information...?

Comment: It does provide useful information.  Unfortunately, using `snow` would require modifying the caret source code, and using `doRNG` fails.

Comment: Nowadays one can use `library(doMC)` - see http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/parallel.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

One easy way to run fully reproducible model in parallel mode using the `caret` package is by using the seeds argument when calling the train control. Here the above question is resolved, check the trainControl help page for further infos.

```
library(doParallel); library(caret)

#create a list of seed, here change the seed for each resampling
set.seed(123)

#length is = (n_repeats*nresampling)+1
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 11)

#(3 is the number of tuning parameter, mtry for rf, here equal to ncol(iris)-2)
for(i in 1:10) seeds[[i]]<- sample.int(n=1000, 3)

#for the last model
seeds[[11]]<-sample.int(1000, 1)

 #control list
 myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', seeds=seeds, index=createFolds(iris$Species))

 #run model in parallel
 cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
 registerDoParallel(cl)
 model1 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

 model2 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)
 stopCluster(cl)

 #compare
 all.equal(predict(model1, type='prob'), predict(model2, type='prob'))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is new functionality in the caret package since I asked the question.  Thanks for keeping me up-to-date!

Comment: @BBrill I have a question, what If I set seeds=NA in the trainControl function?

Answer (score 8):

So caret uses the foreach package to parallelize. There is most likely a way to set the seed at each iteration, but we would need to setup more options in `train`.

Alternatively, you could create a custom modeling function that mimics the internal one for random forests and set the seed yourself.

Max

Answer (score 0):

Which version of caret were you using?

@BBrill's answer is correct. However, since v6.0.64 (Jan 15, 2016), caret takes this issue into account. You may provide your customized `trControl$seeds`, but you don't have to. If `trControl$seeds` is `NULL`, caert will automatically generate those for you, which ensures reproducibility even when for parallel training.

This behavior can be found at https://github.com/topepo/caret/commit/9f375a1704e413d0806b73ab8891c7fadc39081c

Pull request: https://github.com/topepo/caret/pull/353

Related code snippets:

```
    if(is.null(trControl$seeds) || all(is.na(trControl$seeds)))  {
      seeds <- sample.int(n = 1000000L, size = num_rs * nrow(trainInfo$loop) + 1L)
      seeds <- lapply(seq(from = 1L, to = length(seeds), by = nrow(trainInfo$loop)),
                      function(x) { seeds[x:(x+nrow(trainInfo$loop)-1L)] })
      seeds[[num_rs + 1L]] <- seeds[[num_rs + 1L]][1L]
      trControl$seeds <- seeds
    } else {
      (... omitted ...)
    }
```

For more details, you may