# controlling seeds with mclapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, seeding, random-seed

Imagine we are doing a number of processes where i want to set one overall seed at the beginning of a program: e.g.

```
mylist <- list( as.list(rep(NA,3)), as.list(rep(NA,3)) )
foo <- function(x){  for(i in 1:length(x)){ 
                       x[[i]] <- sample(100,1)
                         }
                      return(x) 
                     } 

# start block
set.seed(1)
l1 <- lapply(mylist, foo)
l2 <- lapply(mylist, foo)
# end
```

of course within a block `l1` and `l2` are different, but if i run the above block again `l1` will be the same as before and `l2` will be the same as before.

Imagine `foo` is horribly time consuming so i want to use `mclapply` not `lapply`, so i do:

```
library(parallel)

# start block
set.seed(1)
mclapply(mylist , foo,  mc.cores = 3)
mclapply(mylist , foo,  mc.cores = 3)
# end
```

If i run this block again I will get different results the next time. How do I produce the same behaviour as with setting one overall seed with `lapply` but using `mclappy`. I have looked through `mclapply` doc but I am not sure because using:

```
set.seed(1)
l1 <-  mclapply(mylist , foo,  mc.cores = 3, mc.set.seed=FALSE)
l2 <-  mclapply(mylist , foo,  mc.cores = 3, mc.set.seed=FALSE)
```

result in `l1` and `l2` being the same, which is not what I want...

Comment: You can use `clusterSetupRNG` ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358098/how-to-set-seed-for-random-simulations-with-foreach-and-domc-packages

Comment: cheers but the library(doRNG) example appears to be dated and no longer functional and the clusterSetupRNG is not really quite what i requested, unless you can show me otherwise.

Comment: Seems to have changed slightly... have a look at pg three of the [`doRNG reference manual`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/index.html). Or use `snow`

Comment: Actually the help page for `?'%dorng%'` gives an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `parallel` package comes with special support for the "L'Ecuyer-CMRG" random number generator which was introduced at the same time as `parallel`. You can read the documentation for that support using:

```
library(parallel)
?mc.reset.stream
```

To use it, you first need to enable "L'Ecuyer-CMRG":

```
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
```

After doing that, code such as:

```
set.seed(1)
mclapply(mylist, foo, mc.cores=3)
mclapply(mylist, foo, mc.cores=3)
```

will be reproducible, but the two calls to `mclapply` will return identical results. This is because the state of the random number generator in the master process isn't changed by calling `mclapply`.

I've used the following function to skip over the random number streams used by the `mclapply` workers:

```
skip.streams <- function(n) {
  x <- .Random.seed
  for (i in seq_len(n))
    x <- nextRNGStream(x)
  assign('.Random.seed', x, pos=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

You can use this function to get the behavior that I think you want:

```
set.seed(1)
mclapply(mylist, foo, mc.cores=3)
skip.streams(3)
mclapply(mylist, foo, mc.cores=3)
skip.streams(3)
```